# re-installing group of programs on a new pc or virtual machine

Tags: postfix, dovecot, clamav

OS:OpenSuSE 42.3 64 bit

I have spent a long time configuring a mail server, and I would like to bundle it up in some way so I can easily re-deploy it if the host needs to be re-installed.

For example a virus wipes it out or hardware failure.

I have configured postfix with dovecot, clamav,dkim, dovecot, rspam, spam assassin, openssl and more.

I would like to continue to be able to keep tweaking as time goes on.

This entails a complex changing of file system permissions,adding users, generating keys and etc.

I thought about a container like lxc, docker, or etc.  That the best choice?  Which one?

How do I gather all of these settings and etc so I can easily re-install the exact same config on a brand new machine.  The current machine has become bloated with old files and stuff that hasn't been cleaned up.  I want to start a new VM migrate all the current stuff over, and delete the old VM.

If a container is the answer, how do I gather up all the changes I made and get them into a container?

A contain seems like it would make it easier to duplicate the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want some form of configuration management like [Salt Stack](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/)
 (possibly [masterless](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html) or [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_getting_started.html) or one of various others.

These tools may take a bit to get into but they solve the exact problem you are facing: how to provision a new machine exactly to spec. With these tools you can put your configuration and setup into a git repo somewhere then on a new machine or vm you simply need to bootstrap the install of salt or ansible and let it do the rest by following the rules in your repo.

---

Ansible might be what you want - it allows you to write 'playbooks' of configurations files and commands to run and execute them remotely over ssh. So that when you create a new server you simply run an ansible playbook against it to completely configure it.

---

I have more experience with saltstack so can give you a more detailed examples of using it in a masterless setup. In repo that contains two files:

`wheel.sls` which ensures sudo is installed and 
disables the password timeout

```
sudo:
  pkg.installed

/etc/sudoers.d/wheel:
  file.managed:
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 440
    - contents: |
        %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
        Defaults passwd_timeout=0
```

and `top.sls` - what salt uses to decide which states to run on which machines, in this case everything will run wheel.sls

```
base:
  '*':
    - wheel
```

Then simply install salt-minion on the target vm/server and give it the config similar to the following in `/etc/salt/minion`

```
file_client: local
fileserver_backend:
  - git
gitfs_remotes:
  - git@github.com:user/repo.git:
    - pubkey: /etc/salt/ssh/github.pub
    - privkey: /etc/salt/ssh/github
```

Replacing the github url with the one for your repo and the public/private keys with ones that have access to that repo. Naturally you can extend this to do more then install a single package and write a single file, for a more complete example checkout [this repo](https://github.com/mdaffin/salt-arch) which contains the public half of my setup (naturally most of the config is in a private repo but should be enough to give you some ideas).

For more complicated setups you can run a dedicated master - or even run salt over ssh.

Comment: I need to extract all the changes I made before I can even begin this.  I tried download and extracting postfix for a test and then diff'ing.  Well it turned up difference, but also many lines of comments were also detected as different.  So now, some how, all lines beginning with # on both the source and target have to have those lines extracted before diff can begin.  Then the whole process has to be automated.  Needs to be a better way.

Comment: I would bite the bullet this one time and manually convert things to a configuration management solution - you only need to do this once per system and your life will be simpler after as all the config will be well defined inside a git repo. One way to do this is to reconfigure your current system with one of the tools mentioned - you can start service by service running it in test mode (ie with salt: `salt-call state.apply test=true`) until it shows no difference to your current system, then run it under a test system/vm to see who it works unders a clean install.

Comment: For configs in salt there are two main ways to manage them - replace the whole file, so you don't care about a small diffs on a new system, as long as it works - or replacing specific lines (that match a pattern) to override specific settings where you only care about a small set of differences. The simple option is to just manage the whole file as it currently is and then slowly over time you can improve upon it or convert it to the second method if you wish. Ansible and the other tools will at least be able to replace the whole file.